# Read a GET request sent from PS3 and return a string

Tags: php, sockets

Ok so I managed to create a script on my modded PS3 that is able to create a socket and send a GET request with a given URI. I send it in this format with a query to eventually check in my server’s database if the key is there or not. `www.myWebsite.com/auth.php?key=JW02D-AASTA-3F8UE-8VZJO`

What I want to do now is to code the server side so it can listen for requests and then return a simple string to the PS3. Because right now, what the PS3 receives when I read the ‘response’ with `recv(Socket, bufferReturn, 10000, 0)....`  is this : [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/ruidG47j). What I would like to receive in the buffer on the PS3 is only “Key is valid” or “Key invalid”, not all of this. So the server side have to return a string or something, because right now it doesnt handle socket GET requests at all. All my auth.php can do right now is show “Key is valid” or “Key invalid on the html page using die() function when looked from my iphone or computer browser. It’s a blank web page with not even an index.html.

I beleive I need to create a socket on the server and do a while loop to know if someone is sending a request. That way I could look at the key query that was part of the GET request sent from the PS3 and send a response (just a little string) back to the PS3 that only say “Key is valid” or “Key invalid”. Should that all be done in auth.php? Im not sure how to setup my website so It can do that and run continiously.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the situation you are communicating from a raw TCP socket to your web server, so the additional data is the http protocol. If you want to skip the http part just search for the empty line which separates the http header from the content. The page is blank because your server sends an answer containing only a `<noscript>` tag which is only displayed by your browser when JavaScript is disabled. The rest of the body is some JavaScript which gets executed but not displayed by browsers. I could not figure out what the JavaScript does since your pastebin does not contain all of the response data, it looks like your reading buffer is not cleared correctly.

Where is `www.myWebsite.com` hosted? Maybe your hoster is adding some stuff to your html which some free webhosters do. If you host the server yourself and don’t know where the JavaScript is coming from check your server for viruses.

Comment: This javasscript is not from me. All my website have is pretty much an auth.php file, it prints "Key is valid" in the body. It's probably the free webhoster that adds this javascript code when there's a request... So If it wasnt trying to do some javascript code, it would give me the right body on the PS3 response buffer?

Comment: I fixed the problem! Thanks you, it was indeed because of the free webhoster, I moved to godaddy and paid for a domain name!